# What are the possible reasons for a page to render on Chrome Mobile Emulator but not the actual device?

Tags: android, google-chrome, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

Suppose there is a page which renders fine on Desktop browsers and also renders fine on Chrome mobile emulator (part of Chrome developer tools) but does not render in Chrome on an actual Android device. What could be the reasons for this discrepancy?

[It seems](https://mobile1st.com/can-trust-chromes-built-emulator/) Google's emulator can send the user agent to the server and can even mimic the screen size. The only thing it can't do according to that post is mimic the "rendering engine". But shouldn't this be the same between Desktop and Mobile, it's still just Chrome right?

Comment: Debug your Application so you can see whats going on -- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en

Comment: There are always some [limitations](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports?hl=en#limitations) when using emulators, because they are faking an environment, so you should never rely on them. However, as @Tasos suggests above, it will be more worthwhile to debug your issue and see what is happening for your particular case, rather than speculating generic reasons for differences.

Comment: I wish it were just "some" limitations. This is 8 years later and the PC and Mac Chrome phone emulation doesn't come close to rendering like the Chrome on an Android or iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem apparently due to chrome versions